# Get result of a Binding in code

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm probably searching for this the wrong way, but:

is there any way to get the resulting value of a binding through code?

Probably something glaring obvious, but I just can't find it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<strike>You just need to call the `ProvideValue` method of the binding. The hard part is that you need to pass a valid `IServiceProvider` to the method...</strike> *EDIT: actually, that's not true... `ProvideValue` returns a `BindingExpression`, not the value of the bound property.*

You can use the following trick:

```
class DummyDO : DependencyObject
{
    public object Value
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(DummyDO), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

}

public object EvalBinding(Binding b)
{
    DummyDO d = new DummyDO();
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(d, DummyDO.ValueProperty, b);
    return d.Value;
}

...

Binding b = new Binding("Foo.Bar.Baz") { Source = dataContext };
object value = EvalBinding(b);
```

Not very elegant, but it works...

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar, but running into issues, I think because I need to use RelativeSource. Any idea how to avoid relativesource getting evaluated with respect to DummyDO instead of the target implicit in the context of the binding?

Comment: @tobriand, I'm not sure I understand... What is your use case?

Comment: Basically, I've got an attached behaviour that I'd like to be able to assign to do things to arbitrarily assigned properties, so I'm passing in a Binding object rather than its result. The idea is I should then be able to evaluate this later once my behaviour activates. Since I'm trying to target a property of WPF controls, though, I end up using RelativeSource etc., which results in messages along the lines of "Property Background was not found on type DummyDO". I.e. it doesn't use the original location of the binding as the point of reference - it uses DummyDO...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27568421/302677 for reference to @tobriand's question :)

Answer (score 0):

For getting the data that is bound to an item, after an event occurs, one can refer to the `DataContext` property. This returns the data item bound.

For example, I wanted to get the text of a TextBox in the TextChanged event.

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var box = sender as TextBox;
    var value = box.DataContext as ObjectName; // ObjectName being the type of object being bound in the list
    ...
}
```

This gets you the value of the binding to a list. Practical for click events and such.