# How do I evaluate a RelativeSource object in code to provide a valid Source equivalent

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I've got a situation where I need to use the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886221/get-result-of-a-binding-in-code) to resolve a binding where the binding refers to a `RelativeSource`. I'm using a custom markup extension to allow me to assign the actual Binding object to a `DependencyProperty`, but unfortunately, when I try to apply the binding against `Value` in `DummyDO`, it attempts to find my path (e.g. `Background`) on the equivalently identified `RelativeSource` to `DummyDO`, which doesn't exist.

I was hoping I might be able to work around this by storing the `serviceProvider` property that gets passed into `ProvideValue`, and using

```
return this.TargetBinding.ProvideValue((IProvideValueTarget)this.ServiceProvider);
```

from the markup extension at a later point, but this results in a very strange null reference exception where nothing accessible is null (my guess is some reference has been invalidated somehow).

The alternative is to store the actual source of the property during my `ProvideValue` method, and then create a new method of `ProvideCurrentValue` that re-evaluates the binding per the `DummyDO` approach later. I just can't work out how to do it! Any help would be much appreciated.

Code below:

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button 
     h:ResponsiveBrush.CentreTrackBrush="True" 
     h:ResponsiveBrush.Binding="{e:PassBinding TargetBinding={Binding Background,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}}}" 
     >
        <Button.Content>Try Me</Button.Content>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

(h:ResponsiveBrush isn't relevant for what we're after - it's the behaviour I'm trying to attach, and crucial part for this is at some point it needs to resolve the Binding object it's been passed via PassBindingExtension)

**Markup Extension**

```
public class PassBindingExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public PassBindingExtension() { }
    public PassBindingExtension(Binding targetBinding) 
    {
        this.TargetBinding = targetBinding;
    }
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var valueGetter = serviceProvider as IProvideValueTarget;
        if (valueGetter != null) 
        { 
            // Get the object. NB that this will evaluate to a 
            // BUTTON given the XAML above NOT a StackPanel as I was hoping
            this.TargetObject = valueGetter.TargetObject; 
            this.TargetProperty = valueGetter.TargetProperty;

            /* 
               Ideally around here I need to evaluate the object to which 
               this. TargetBinding refers around here so I can get the correct
               value later.
            */
        }

        /* 
           Addendum: If I try the following at this point, my application vanishes into
           oblivion

           var oOriginalValue = this.TargetBinding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);

           Not sure if that's intended or not, but since I don't need to get the 
           original value, I just need the info to work out where the future value 
           should come from, I'm not too fussed.
        */

        return this;
    }

    public object ProvideValueLate() 
    {
        object oOut = null;

        /* Somehow, here, I need to reliably obtain 
           the value of TargetProperty on the 
           RelativeSource that would be evaluated with 
           respect to TargetObject 
        */

        return oOut;
    }

    [ConstructorArgument("targetBinding")]
    public Binding TargetBinding { get; set; }

    public object TargetObject { get; set; }

    public object TargetProperty { get; set; }

    // Obsolete - doesn't work
    public IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }

    // Was hoping this would let me sidestep the issue, but lamentably it doesn't
    public object ProvideValueLate_Old()
    {     return this.TargetBinding.ProvideValue((IProvideValueTarget)this.ServiceProvider); }
}
```

Comment: Show your relevant code... your words mean very little without the code.

Comment: I've added the code for the markup extension, as well as how I'm using it in XAML. Basic idea is the gives me the capacity to apply h:ResponsiveBrush to an arbitrary brush property, not e.g. just background or borders.

Comment: I should also point out that at time of writing the question, the intention was to build a new binding that relied on Source instead of RelativeSource, and therefore would bind successfully in DummyDO (from the linked post). This is probably still not a bad way to go about things, but I haven't got the half-finished code to build a new binding in there for purposes of readability.

Answer (score 0):

Right, haven't been able to work this out precisely, but did manage to use a workaround, based on the following:

- `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}` evalutes via standard dependency property to the object in question, where Self could be any RelativeSource.
- Therefore, create two properties on the attached behaviour, one for the object we want the property from, and one for the property path. Call them SourceObject and SourcePath.
- Use the approach below to get the existing value. This is in the event handler for h:ResponsiveBrush - I did NOT manage to make this work using a markup extension (which is what I'd have liked, but can't have it all...):

  ```
  string sourcePath = ((DependencyObject)sender).GetValue(SourcePathProperty);
  DependencyObject sourceObject = ((DependencyObject)sender).GetValue(SourceObjectProperty);
  Binding b = new Binding(sourcePath) {Source = sourceObject};
  RadialGradientBrush sourceBrush = DependencyInterpreter.EvalBinding(b) as RadialGradientBrush;
  ```

Gets me what I needed, but I won't accept this answer for the time being since it does NOT answer the question - just provides a workaround for others in similar situations. If anyone DOES have the answer to why the Markup Extension approach wasn't working, I'd still be extremely interested.